# Benefit to Using Multiple Web Applications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-application

I am considering a scenario of breaking down a global company in SharePoint to use a Web Application for each geographical region. The company has a presence in 5 countries. Considering this, I already have 2 web apps in use for Central Admin, and Search. The first Web App for sites will be Global, where all regions role up information such as announcements etc. The next 5 are for each region. Is this a benefit to utilize Web Apps this way. We have all the server power we need so resources will not be an issue. Is this a scenario anyone has experience with. Comments welcome.

Web Apps Overview

- Central Admin
- Search
- Global Portal - All regions jump from here
- Country 1
- Country 2
- Country 3
- Country 4
- Country 5

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This goes against MS best practices. The current best practices would be to create host named site collections in one web app.

For more on this:
http://sprickyrick.blogspot.com/2013/04/two-new-best-practices-for-sharepoint.html

Comment: Thank you, good read, and helped reached decision of sticking with using HNSC's and limiting Web Apps use.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple web applications depends upon the requirement. Usually people used separate web application if they want to use different URL.

MSFT recommendation are 10 app pools per farm and 20 Web apps. If you want to go with your desired plan, their will be no issue with it. It is not bad idea at all, but `How many site collections we are talking about in each web app?`

If we are talking about the 5 to 10 in each web app then I think multiple web apps will be waste of resources on server.

As an alternate, you use the HNSC site collections that will erase the requirement of all 5 web apps.

Comment: I have been researching and currently developing a model of one web app and using HNSC's. There is no real reason for multiple web apps outside of CA, search, and MySites. It was more for a logical breakdown of the regions. There will be more than 10 Site Collections. Thanks for the responses, I think I will stick with the one Web App and continue with the HNSC's. I was mostly inquiring as to whether any benefit could be derived from using multiple web apps, but it appears nothing worth noting would be gained. Thank you again.

Comment: if you have any customization in shape of solutions which you want to deploy only a specific region's site collections then seprate web app required....customization which required web.config changes...or if their is any change which required at web app level i.e. List view threshold, fileupload limit etc....that are mostly separate web app driven point.

Comment: Thanks Waqas, no customizations which would require the additional Web App. So at this point I am going all HNSC.